# moving data in excel with python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, reshape

I would like to be able to move a data of the table automatically to place it on a new column and duplicate it as many times as I have rows before a row with only one data but I don't know which tool to use.

[image: My data]

Comment: You might wish to rephrase the question to something more appropriate (maybe "moving data in excel with python").

Comment: You need `df['col'] = df['col'].ffill()` ?

Comment: This is going to work. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not a `python`, `pandas` or `dataframe` question but more about *running a macro in excel*.

One can run macro's in excel with python using:  https://www.xlwings.org/
This is open source and free, comes preinstalled with Anaconda and WinPython, and works on Windows and macOS

Although, you might simple prefer the natural `excel vba` editor for this and "record a macro".

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: With macros the problem would indeed be solved immediately, but I'm really trying to do it in Pandas. can be with loc to move my data on another column then by duplicating it?

Comment: You can use `pandas.read_excel` and `pandas.DataFrame.to_excel`, but you would need to make sure that the excel file was not locked from opening (ie. in windows if a file is open it is locked).

Comment: I'm already on pandas.read_excel, no problem here !

Answer (score 0):

Using ffill answer directly the question.

> df['col'] = df['col'].ffill()